# Is it possible to find a basis for a direct sum of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let us consider the following direct sum of groups:

$G=ℤ^{r}⊕ℤ/nℤ$

or

$G=ℤ^{r}⊕ℤ/2mℤ×ℤ/2ℤ$

We know that $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group.

**My question** is: Is it possible to find a **basis** for this group in the sense that every element of the group can be written in one and only one way as a finite linear combination of elements of the basis, with integer coefficients.

Comment: I could be totally wrong but don't we need our group to be free abelian and not just finitely generated to find a basis?

Comment: @AlexJBest : you’re not wrong at all, there seems to be a mistake in the original question.

Comment: @  Alex J Best: I know only that $G$ finitely generated abelian group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any finite abelian group $A$ of order $n$, you cannot find a basis. The reason is that if $x$ is a nonidentity element then $(n+1)x=x$. Thus if $x=\sum_{i=0}^k \alpha_ib_i$ is a linear combination of basis elements $b_i$, then $$x=(n+1)x=\sum_{i=0}^k ((n+1)\alpha_i)b_i.$$
Hence, we can cannot construct a basis for an arbitrary finitely generated abelian group.

Comment: Should this not read $nx=0$ or $(n+1)x = x$?

Comment: @AlexJBest Indeed. Thank you.